# Hidden field value not set properly in ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a function named `getConvertionValue`, from that function I call `getCurrencyConvertion` function written in controller using ajax.

```js
function getConvertionValue(from, to) {
  if (from != to) {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url + 'admin/order/getCurrencyConvertion',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        from: from,
        to: to
      },
      success: function(result) {
        result = $.parseJSON(result);
        $.each(result, function(key, element) {
          var rate = element.abc_convertion_rate;
          rate = parseFloat(rate);
          $('#divider').val(rate).change();
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('#divider').val(1).change();
  }
}
```

In the above ajax success function I had set hidden field value.and i have to use that hidden field value.

```
getCovertionValue(from, to);
$("#divider").change(function() {
  var divider = $(this).val();
  alert(divider);
});
```

As u seen in my ajax success function i have checked the value of rate and value of hidden field named 'divider', no problem in that section But the value not get correctly at `$("#divider").change(function()` portion. I am new here someone please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Try using callbacks.

Comment: @BrahmaDev They are the same thing

Comment: You need to bind the event using "on" you need because this event no exist when the body is loaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right.

Comment: Can you paste your `#divider` markup and the `result` json you're getting in your ajax function?

Comment: You're setting the value of the field in a loop, so you're most likely only going to see the final value that's set in the `change` event handler. It would help a lot to see your HTML and the response text of the AJAX request here

Answer (score 1):

Use text() instead of val().

**.val()**  works on input elements (or any element with a value attribute?) and **.text()**  will not work on input elements.

**.val()**  gets the value of the input element -- regardless of type. **.text()**  gets the innerText (not HTML) of all the matched elements:

Comment: The OP states they are working on a hidden input, so your own question is giving the opposite advice to what they need